# Input aligned left, in center of div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align my input sections in the center of the div, with the labels left aligned on the left of the input. I can't seem to get the input sections to align to the left of each other, in the center of the div. Bear with me, I'm incredibly new to coding of any sort so my code might not be the best. 
Here is my html and css thus far:
This is what I would like it to look like. Label on the left, input field in the center. [IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQBIG.png)

```css
.othercomponent {
   background-color: white;
   height: 30px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   width: 95%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   margin-top: 10px;
   text-indent: 10px;
   font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: medium;
   font-weight: bold;
   display: block;
}

.lpks-input {
   width: 35%;
   display: inline-block;
   padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body class="body">
   <div class="othercomponent">Plot Name <input class="lpks-input"></div>
   <div class="othercomponent">Other Name <input class="lpks-input"></div>
</body>
```

Here is a JSFiddle to show what I have now:
https://jsfiddle.net/h8vo2opv/

Comment: can you post an image of the desired effect?

Comment: So you want the text at the left of the div and the inputfield in the middle?

Comment: I will post an image soon. And correct, Stefan. I would like the text at the left and the input field in the center.

Comment: I updated my answer not same as ur picture. but label on left and textbox on center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `width` for div. And place `<label>` for your text in left section and put style `float:left;`
set width for label and input section also. check my code this will help you.

```css
.othercomponent {
   background-color: white;
height: 30px;
border-radius: 10px;
width:100%;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 10px;
text-indent: 10px;
font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
/* font-size: medium; */
font-weight: bold;
display: block;
align-items: center;

background: wheat;
   }
.othercomponent input {
  width: 60%;
  float:left;
  }
.othercomponent lebel {
    float: left;
  width:30%;
}

    .lpks-input {
 width: 35%;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-right: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<body class="body">
  <div class="othercomponent"><lebel>Plot Name </lebel><input class="lpks-input"></div>

  <div class="othercomponent"><lebel>Other Name </lebel><input class="lpks-input"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you !

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please consider accepting the answer [(see How to accept SO answers)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 0):

If i understood well :) you want them in center of white div :

HTML :

```
   <body class="body">
     <div class="othercomponent">
 <span class="left">Plot Name </span> <span class="center"><input class="lpks-input"></span></div>

     <div class="othercomponent">
  <span class="left">Plot Name </span> <span class="center"> <input class="lpks-input"></span></div>
```

CSS:

```
    .body {
    background-color: #EDEDED;
}

.othercomponent {
    background-color: white;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-indent: 10px;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: small;
  text-align:center;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: block;
}

.lpks-input {
    width: 35%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 5px;

}
.left{
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: Actually, I'm just trying to get the 'input' in the center, left aligned with the other inputs, but the label to stay on the left side of the div. Thank you for your response, though!

Comment: But if the two labels are different in length, the input field will move farther to the right.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a bit of markup and then style your `form` like a `table`.  This will line up the `input`s based on the `label` widths.

```css
.form {
  display: table;
}

.othercomponent {
 background-color: white;
 height: 30px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 width: 95%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 10px;
 text-indent: 10px;
 font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: medium;
 font-weight: bold;
 /* display: block; */
 display: table-row;
   }

    .lpks-input {
 /* width: 35%; */
 display: inline-block;
 padding-right: 5px;
    }

label,
.input-container {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<body class="body">
  <form>
  <div class="othercomponent"><label for="input1">Plot Name</label><div class="input-container"><input id="input1" class="lpks-input"></div></div>

  <div class="othercomponent"><label for="input2">Other Name</label><div class="input-container"><input id="input2" class="lpks-input"></div></div>
  </form>
</body>
```